# Bochner nonnegativity theorem for Laplace-Beltrami eigenfunctions?

Tags: fourier-analysis, riemannian-geometry, harmonic-analysis, laplacian

Suppose $\psi_0,\psi_1,\ldots\in L_2(M)$ are the Laplace-Beltrami eigenfunctions of a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$.  Furthermore, take $f(x):=\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i\psi_i(x)$ to be a function on $M$ with coefficients $\{a_i\}_{i=0}^\infty$.  **Is there a necessary/sufficient condition on the $a_i$'s guaranteeing that $f(x)\geq0$ for all $x\in M$?**

My inspiration here is the [Bochner theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner%27s_theorem) from harmonic analysis, whose proof seems to depend on having stronger structure ([Lie group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_function_on_a_group)) than just a general manifold $(M,g)$.

Answer (score 0):

Sufficient conditions do exist. For instance, the kernel of the associated heat semigroup
$$k_t(x,y) = \sum_{i} e^{-t \lambda_i} \psi_i(x) \psi_i(y),$$
where $\lambda_i$ is the eigenvalue associated with $\psi_i$, is positive. Therefore, all functions of the form
$$
f(x) = \int_{M \times \mathbb{R_+}} k_t(x,y) \, d \mu(y,t)
= \sum_{i = 1}^\infty \bigg( \int_{M \times \mathbb{R_+}} \psi_i(y) e^{-
 t \, \lambda_i}  \, d \mu(y,t) \bigg) \, \psi_i(x)
$$
are also positive provided that $\mu$ is a finite positive measure. I ignore whether those are all the positive functions.

Comment: Thanks!  Unfortunately I'll need necessary conditions, or at least a sufficiently wide set of sufficient conditions to reasonably approximate most functions in the function space.